# Elasticsearch array of nested objects with aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an object with structure shown below

```
{
   "field1": "textual data",
   "field2": "another data",
   "services": [
       {
           "id": "123",
           "type": "type1",
           "price": 124.5
       },
       {
           "id": "345",
           "type": "type2",
           "price": 321.5
       },
       {
           "id": "47",
           "type": "type4",
           "price": 21.5
       }
   ]
}
```

Could anyone provide any ideas about creating index for addressing next use case: find all objects with services having types X1, X2, X3 and their total price lesser than M.

Any advices on constructing a query also appreciated!